Failing creation topic with few brokers on the same host in the docker swarm mode
Version & Environment
Redpanda version: (use rpk version): v24.2.12
Versions of other components:

Operating System (e.g. from /etc/os-release): Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Docker (use docker info): 27.4.0

What went wrong?
I can't create a topic (even with 1 partition) with brokers running on the same host in docker swarm mode.
What should have happened instead?
I want to run 3 brokers on one node. I also want to create a topic (ideally with 500 partitions).
How to reproduce the issue?

Create stack.yaml file with 3 brokers

services:
  redpanda1:
    image: redpandadata/redpanda:v24.2.12
    container_name: redpanda1
    hostname: redpanda1
    ports:
      - "9644:9644"
    environment:
      - REDPANDA_NODE_ID=1
      - REDPANDA_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://redpanda1:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=0.0.0.0:9644
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=redpanda1:9644
      - REDPANDA_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/redpanda/data
      - REDPANDA_LOG_LEVEL=warn
      - REDPANDA_ENABLE_RACK_AWARE_REPLICATION=false
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_BYTES=536870912
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_MS=60000
      - REDPANDA_SEGMENT_BYTES=104857600
      - REDPANDA_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_SEED_SERVERS=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
    volumes:
      - redpanda_data1:/var/lib/redpanda/data
    networks:
      - backend-net
      - redpanda-net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4G
          cpus: "2.0"

  redpanda2:
    image: redpandadata/redpanda:v24.2.12
    container_name: redpanda2
    hostname: redpanda2
    ports:
      - "9645:9644"
    environment:
      - REDPANDA_NODE_ID=2
      - REDPANDA_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://redpanda2:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=0.0.0.0:9644
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=redpanda2:9644
      - REDPANDA_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/redpanda/data
      - REDPANDA_LOG_LEVEL=warn
      - REDPANDA_ENABLE_RACK_AWARE_REPLICATION=false
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_BYTES=536870912
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_MS=60000
      - REDPANDA_SEGMENT_BYTES=104857600
      - REDPANDA_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_SEED_SERVERS=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
    volumes:
      - redpanda_data2:/var/lib/redpanda/data
    networks:
      - backend-net
      - redpanda-net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4G
          cpus: "2.0"

  redpanda3:
    image: redpandadata/redpanda:v24.2.12
    container_name: redpanda3
    hostname: redpanda3
    ports:
      - "9646:9644"
    environment:
      - REDPANDA_NODE_ID=3
      - REDPANDA_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://redpanda3:9092
      - REDPANDA_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=0.0.0.0:9644
      - REDPANDA_ADVERTISED_ADMIN_API_LISTENERS=redpanda3:9644
      - REDPANDA_LOG_DIR=/var/lib/redpanda/data
      - REDPANDA_LOG_LEVEL=warn
      - REDPANDA_ENABLE_RACK_AWARE_REPLICATION=false
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_BYTES=536870912
      - REDPANDA_RETENTION_MS=60000
      - REDPANDA_SEGMENT_BYTES=104857600
      - REDPANDA_REPLICATION_FACTOR=3
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_CONTROLLER_EXTERNAL_CONNECT=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
      - REDPANDA_SEED_SERVERS=redpanda1:33145,redpanda2:33145,redpanda3:33145
    volumes:
      - redpanda_data3:/var/lib/redpanda/data
    networks:
      - backend-net
      - redpanda-net
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 4G
          cpus: "2.0"

volumes:
  redpanda_data1:
  redpanda_data2:
  redpanda_data3:

networks:
  backend-net:
    external: true
  redpanda-net:
    external: true

When I try create topic from redpanda1 container I get error
INFO  2024-12-19 20:28:10,656 [shard  1:main] cluster - topics_frontend.cc:210 - Create topics [{configuration: { topic: {kafka/atr}, partition_count: 1, replication_factor: 3, is_migrated: false, properties: {compression: {nullopt}, cleanup_policy_bitflags: {nullopt}, compaction_strategy: {nullopt}, retention_bytes: {}, retention_duration_ms: {}, segment_size: {nullopt}, timestamp_type: {nullopt}, recovery_enabled: {nullopt}, shadow_indexing: {disabled}, read_replica: {nullopt}, read_replica_bucket: {nullopt}, remote_topic_namespace_override: {nullopt}, remote_topic_properties: {nullopt}, batch_max_bytes: {nullopt}, retention_local_target_bytes: {}, retention_local_target_ms: {}, remote_delete: true, segment_ms: {}, record_key_schema_id_validation: {nullopt}, record_key_schema_id_validation_compat: {nullopt}, record_key_subject_name_strategy:  {nullopt}, record_key_subject_name_strategy_compat: {nullopt}, record_value_schema_id_validation: {nullopt},  record_value_schema_id_validation_compat: {nullopt}, record_value_subject_name_strategy: {nullopt}, record_value_subject_name_strategy_compat: {nullopt}, initial_retention_local_target_bytes: {}, initial_retention_local_target_ms: {}, mpx_virtual_cluster_id: {nullopt}, write_caching: {nullopt}, flush_ms: {nullopt}, flush_bytes: {nullopt}, remote_label: {nullopt}}}, custom_assignments: {}},]

2024-12-19T20:28:10.656623161Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | WARN  2024-12-19 20:28:10,656 [shard  1:main] kafka - create_topics.cc:159 - Failed to create topic(s) {{kafka/atr}} error_code observed: cluster::errc::topic_invalid_replication_factor

I tried different partitions (1, 3, 150, 500 etc)
I see following logs after startup container
2024-12-19T20:22:20.499172662Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,499 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:2664 - Started Schema Registry listening at {{:{host: 0.0.0.0, port: 8081}:<nullopt>}}
2024-12-19T20:22:20.499316311Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,499 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:2999 - Waiting for cluster membership
2024-12-19T20:22:20.499322243Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,499 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:3017 - Waiting for Cluster ID to initialize...
2024-12-19T20:22:20.502204557Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,502 [shard  0:main] cluster - members_manager.cc:164 - Node configuration updated successfully
2024-12-19T20:22:20.502795144Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,502 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:3028 - Started Kafka API server listening at {{:{host: 0.0.0.0, port: 9092}:{nullopt}}}
2024-12-19T20:22:20.503196617Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,503 [shard  0:main] cluster - metrics_reporter.cc:409 - Initialized cluster_id to aca7dfc6-ba85-4319-90b8-47128d2bb90e
2024-12-19T20:22:20.503568734Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:20,503 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:2707 - Successfully started Redpanda!
2024-12-19T20:22:23.484328900Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:23,484 [shard  0:main] cluster - partition_balancer_planner.cc:1972 - counts rebalancing objective in domain -1: 1 -> 1
2024-12-19T20:22:23.484354698Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:23,484 [shard  0:main] cluster - partition_balancer_planner.cc:1972 - counts rebalancing objective in domain 0: 1 -> 1
2024-12-19T20:22:23.484358876Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:23,484 [shard  0:main] cluster - partition_balancer_backend.cc:423 - last status: in_progress; violations: unavailable nodes: 0, full nodes: 0; nodes to rebalance count: 1; on demand rebalance requested: false; updates in progress: 0; action counts: reassignments: 0, cancellations: 0, failed: 0; counts rebalancing finished: true, force refresh health report: false
2024-12-19T20:22:23.484563841Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:22:23,484 [shard  0:main] cluster - members_manager.cc:375 - applying finish_reallocations_cmd, offset: 8, node id: 0
2024-12-19T20:23:19.963522505Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:23:19,963 [shard  0:main] main - memory_sampling.cc:143 - 34812723 bytes of available memory left - Top-N alloc sites: size: 33554432 count: 2 at: 0xa66e23a 0xa2aadd6 0xa2b43d6 0xa2a6bce 0x96b50f7 0x96b5e46 0x96b49d3 0x32ff1a3 0x335f9a2 0xa49ffeb|size: 21000259 count: 7 at: 0xa66e23a 0xa2aadd6 0xa2b34cf 0xa2bf9c8 0x969843f 0x344c8da 0xa39f22f 0xa3a2951 0xa39fb16 0xa27de00 0xa27c1f8 0x32fc17d 0xa8ea329 /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a087 /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a14a 0x32f4624|size: 18000222 count: 6 at: 0xa66e23a 0xa2cb4a0 0xa2b3b57 0xa2a6bce 0x3656fe1 0x365780c 0xa39f22f 0xa3a2951 0xa39fb16 0xa27de00 0xa27c1f8 0x32fc17d 0xa8ea329 /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a087 /opt/redpanda/lib/libc.so.6+0x2a14a 0x32f4624|size: 8388608 count: 1 at: 0xa66e23a 0xa2aadd6 0xa2b43d6 0xa2a6bce 0x96c469d 0x96c4b7f 0x32ff1bc 0x335f9a2 0xa49ffeb|size: 4194304 count: 1 at: 0xa66e23a 0xa2aadd6 0xa2b43d6 0xa2a6bce 0x96b4d34 0x96b547b 0x96b49d3 0x32ff1a3 0x335f9a2 0xa49ffeb
2024-12-19T20:23:20.481709784Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:23:20,481 [shard  0:main] cluster - controller_stm.cc:136 - created snapshot at offset 8 in 0 ms
2024-12-19T20:23:20.492409816Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | INFO  2024-12-19 20:23:20,492 [shard  0:main] storage - disk_log_impl.cc:2486 - Removing "/var/lib/redpanda/data/redpanda/controller/0_0/0-1-v1.log" (remove_prefix_full_segments, {offset_tracker:{term:1, base_offset:0, committed_offset:8, dirty_offset:8}, compacted_segment=0, finished_self_compaction=0, finished_windowed_compaction=0, generation=18, reader={/var/lib/redpanda/data/redpanda/controller/0_0/0-1-v1.log, (1545 bytes)}, writer={no_of_chunks:64, closed:0, fallocation_offset:33554432, stable_offset:1545, flushed_offset:1545, committed_offset:1545, inflight:0, dispatched:0, merged:0, bytes_flush_pending:0}, cache={cache_size=9, dirty tracker: {min: -9223372036854775808, max: -9223372036854775808}}, compaction_index:nullopt, closed=0, tombstone=0, index={file:/var/lib/redpanda/data/redpanda/controller/0_0/0-1-v1.base_index, offsets:0, index:{header_bitflags:0, base_offset:0, max_offset:8, base_timestamp:{timestamp: 1734639740355}, max_timestamp:{timestamp: 1734639743484}, batch_timestamps_are_monotonic:1, with_offset:false, non_data_timestamps:0, broker_timestamp:{{timestamp: 1734639743484}}, num_compactible_records_appended:{8}, index(1,1,1)}, step:32768, needs_persistence:1}})
2024-12-19T20:28:10.656542950Z infra_redpanda1.1.yx4mq8vckkyn@dev    | 

Also I see next errors logs
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,305 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,306 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,307 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,307 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,307 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,307 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,307 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,308 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,308 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,308 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,309 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,309 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,309 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,310 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,310 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,310 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,310 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,311 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,311 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,311 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,311 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,312 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,313 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,313 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,313 seastar - Creation of perf_event based stall detector failed: falling back to posix timer: std::__1::system_error (error system:1, perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted)
WARN  2024-12-19 22:25:32,313 cpu_profiler - Creation of perf_event based cpu profiler failed: falling back to posix timer: perf_event_open() failed: Operation not permitted
INFO  2024-12-19 22:25:32,321 [shard  0:main] cluster - config_manager.cc:510 - Can't load config cache: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error (error system:2, filesystem error: open failed: No such file or directory ["/var/lib/redpanda/data/config_cache.yaml"])
INFO  2024-12-19 22:25:32,321 [shard  0:main] cluster - config_manager.cc:450 - Can't load config bootstrap file: std::__1::__fs::filesystem::filesystem_error (error system:2, filesystem error: open failed: No such file or directory ["/etc/redpanda/.bootstrap.yaml"])

INFO  2024-12-19 22:25:32,325 [shard  0:main] main - application.cc:523 - Setting abort_on_allocation_failure (abort on OOM): true
ERROR 2024-12-19 22:25:32,330 [shard  0:main] syschecks - Memory: '174063616' below recommended: '1073741824'

WARN  2024-12-19 22:26:36,192 [shard  1:main] kafka - create_topics.cc:159 - Failed to create topic(s) {{kafka/atr}} error_code observed: cluster::errc::topic_invalid_replication_factor
WARN  2024-12-19 22:26:43,377 [shard  1:main] kafka - create_topics.cc:159 - Failed to create topic(s) {{kafka/atr}} error_code observed: cluster::errc::topic_invalid_replication_factor
WARN  2024-12-19 22:26:50,994 [shard  1:main] kafka - create_topics.cc:159 - Failed to create topic(s) {{kafka/atr}} error_code observed: cluster::errc::topic_invalid_replication_factor
WARN  2024-12-19 22:27:03,188 [shard  1:main] kafka - create_topics.cc:159 - Failed to create topic(s) {{kafka/atr}} error_code observed: cluster::errc::topic_invalid_replication_factor

